# AngularJS Element Directive Not rendering on the HTML

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

My AngularJS directive is not working, can anyone please tell me what's wrong with my code.
I have created directives in the past but my code is not working anymore

This is my Plunkr https://plnkr.co/edit/Tf9h4b05bSyueALVSmW8?p=preview

This is correct right ?

```js
app.directive('ChartHorizontal', function() {
  var directive = {};
  directive.restrict = 'E';
  directive.template = '<h3>Hello Ji</h3>';

  return directive;
});
```

and in HTML we will do `<chart-horizontal></chart-horizontal>` Do we need a controller ?
If yes, I have already doing it in controller in my project.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Works fine in this DEMO:

```js
angular.module("app",[]).directive('chartHorizontal', function() {
  var directive = {};
  directive.restrict = 'E';
  directive.template = '<h3>Hello Ji</h3>';

  return directive;
});
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/angular/angular.js"></script>
<body ng-app="app">
   <chart-horizontal></chart-horizontal>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you, I don't know what was the problem. I copy pasted your code in plunkr and it worked. So I took your code and implemented in my project. I think your Angular Library is the reason. I'm not sure though because the library which i was importing was also working for my other projects.